# Why does ActionController process image requests, but not process streaming requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, video, actioncontroller

When some image was not found (it's "src" attribute points to wrong path), i get following error:

> Processing ApplicationController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-12 16:44:19) [GET]
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "non-existent-image.jpg" with {:method=>:get}):
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:109:in `debug_load'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:109:in`debug_program'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/bin/rdebug-ide:87
>     /usr/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
>     /usr/bin/rdebug-ide:19
>     -e:2:in`load'
>     -e:2
>
> Rendering rescues/layout (not_found)

But, when there is a HTML5 video element, i don't see any complains of ActionController, when it is not found.

What's going on here ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're generating HTML that looks like `<img src="/non-existent-image.jpg">` and that path is not defined in your `config/routes.rb` so it can't be handled by the Rails application.

What you might be intending is:

```
<%= image_tag('non-existent-image.jpg') %>
```

This will generate a tag that looks like:

```
<img src="/images/non-existent-image.jpg">
```

So long as that file is present in your `public/` folder, it should work.